# C# foreach join or groupby? I am trying to get a total

Tags: c#

Fairly new with C# and still learning a lot. I'm in a pickle and wondering if I could get some help. I have researched and just cannot find the answer.

I have a foreach statement on LaborHed and I am gathering work hours based on clockin/clockout. Works great for those that don't leave the premises for lunch. These employees must clock out for lunch and then clock back in creating another LaborHed record. I am trying to combine the labor hours of the two and then determine overtime. I then write out everything to a .csv file.
Is there some sort of join or grouping or something that could be applied??

```
foreach (var LaborHed_iterator in (from LaborHed_Row in Db.LaborHed
                                   where LaborHed_Row.ClockInDate >= (DateTime?)ttUD06Row.Date01 && LaborHed_Row.ClockInDate <= (DateTime?)ttUD06Row.Date02
                                   orderby LaborHed_Row.EmployeeNum, LaborHed_Row.ClockInDate
                                   select LaborHed_Row))
{
    LaborHed2 = (from LaborHed2_Row in Db.LaborHed
                 where LaborHed2_Row.ClockInDate == LaborHed.ClockInDate && LaborHed2_Row.EmployeeNum == strEmpNum
                 select LaborHed2_Row). // All LaborHed records for selected ClockinDate by Employee for Shop Employees only

    if (LaborHed2 != null)
    {
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    var empWorkTimes = Db.LaborHeds.Where(x => x.ClockInDate >= DateTime.Now && x.ClockOutDate <= DateTime.Now)
        .OrderBy(x => x.ClockInDate)
        .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeNum)
     .Select(x => new { EmployeeNum = x.Key, TotalHours = x.Sum(l => (l.ClockOutDate - l.ClockInDate).TotalHours) });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ClockOutDate is not a column in the table... This is how I calculate TotHours for each LaborHed.



TotDay = (LaborHed2.ClockOutTime - LaborHed2.ClockInTime);
                      TotLunch = (LaborHed2.LunchInTime - LaborHed2.LunchOutTime);
                      TotHours = TotHours + (TotDay - TotLunch);

Comment: treat this just as a starting point and apply your own logic for calculating the hours

Comment: I changed to: var empWorkTimes = Db.LaborHed.Where(x => x.ClockInDate >= (DateTime?)ttUD06Row.Date01 && x.ClockInDate <= (DateTime?)ttUD06Row.Date02)
        .OrderBy(x => x.ClockInDate)
        .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeNum)
     .Select(x =>
     {
        var totalHours = x.Sum(l => (l.ClockOutTime - l.ClockInTime));
        return new { EmployeeNum = x.Key, TotalHours = totalHours };
     });
     }
But I get an error: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: Yes, I can see the reference to EntityFramework. I am developing in Epicor 10.

Comment: Try changing your Select to `.Select(x => new { EmployeeNum = x.Key, TotalHours = x.Sum(l => (l.ClockOutTime - l.ClockInTime)) });`

Comment: That did. Now a very dumb question... How do I read or use the data from the select?

Comment: you could do a `foreach x on empWorkTimes` and access `x.EmployeeNum` and `x.TotalHours`

Comment: foreach (x on empWorkTimes)
     {
     } 
Gives me errors. in expected and the type or namespace name 'x' could not be found. I'm sorry. I'm still a C# dummy.

Comment: Please go thru the tutorial [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

Comment: Still lost. I guess I will figure it out. Thank you very much for all of your help.

Comment: I'm making progress and figuring it out. One very last question I promise. Why is EmployeeNum coming over as a DateTime, the ClockInDate?
foreach (var WorkHours in empWorkTimes)
             {
                strEmpNum = Convert.ToString(WorkHours.EmployeeNum);
}

Comment: double check the values in LaborHed table in db for the EmployeeNum column. what is its data type?

Comment: EmployeeNum is nvarchar

Comment: I got it. OrderBy and GroupBy was reversed so the key was ClockinDate... Ugh. Thanks!

Comment: However, now I get total work hours for the week instead of total work hours per day.

Comment: change the GroupBy to `.GroupBy(x => new { x.EmployeeNum, x.ClockInDate} )` and Select to `.Select(x => new { EmployeeNum = x.Key.EmployeeNum, Date = x.Key.ClockInDate, TotalHours = x.Sum(l => (l.ClockOutTime - l.ClockInTime).TotalHours) });`